# How to use the R environment and the globalenv() function

Tags: r, environment-variables, storage, environment, scoping

I'm currently reading *Hands-On Programming With R* and the author first suggests this code to deal cards from the top of a deck:

```
deal <- function(deck) {
deck[1,]}
```

but that code has an obvious problem: you'll always get the same card, since the function does not remove the card from the deck after it has been dealt.

As a solution, he suggests this code:

```
deal <- function(){
  card <- deck[1,]
  assign("deck", deck[-1,], envir = globalenv())
  card
```

I feel like I don't properly understand what's going on with the *envir = globalenv()* part. I do know that it has something to do with removing the card that has been dealt from the deck, but can someone please elucidate what is happening there exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your card deck is stored in a vector `deck` in your Global Environment.

```r
deal <- function(){
  card <- deck[1,]
  assign("deck", deck[-1,], envir = globalenv())
  card
}
```

Each function call creates it's own environment, an object assigned inside a function "lives" just inside of it. That's why you don't "see" a vector named `card` in your Global Environment (unless you created one before, but this vector is uneffected by `deal` functions `card <- deck[1,]` statement).

So `assign("deck", deck[-1])` (without the `envir` argument) would be the same as

```r
deal <- function(){
  card <- deck[1,]
  deck <- deck[-1,]
  card
}
```

but this won't change your `deck` *outside* the function. The vector `deck` inside the function just exists inside the function. To change the `deck` outside the function, you have to tell `R` *where* to change it. So that's why `assign("deck", deck[-1,], envir = globalenv())` is used.

So let's start over with your function `deal`:

```
card <- deck[1,]
```

assigns the first element of `deck` to `card`. But wait! `deck` doesn't exists *inside* the function? So how is this possible? If the object isn't found *inside* the function, `R` looks one level up, in your case most likely the Global Environment. So there R finds an object/vector named `deck` and does the assignment. Now we have an object/vector named `card` that exists inside the function.

For further understanding, take a look at [Chapter 6: Functions in Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Reading more about the *globalenv* and *assign* functions, I came across some **key information**:

- *envir* is the argument that determines what environment to use
- the globalenv function simply gives us acess to the global environment
- runtime environment is the

> hardware and software infrastructure that supports the running of
> a particular codebase in real time

- Global Environment is

> the interactive workspace [...] in which you normally work

With that in mind, I **translated the code** to:

> > R, create a *deal* function, in which you'll first:
> >
> > 1. Create an object called *card* - and it's value will be the first row of the object *deck*
> > 2. Remove that first row of the object deck - not only from the *runtime environment*, but from the *global environment*
> > 3. Return the value of the object *card*